# Drupal 8 views entity reference exposed filter based on node reference

Tags: view, filtering, drupal-8, entityreference

I have a problem in filtering a views with an entity referenced field.

I have a content type called "product" and a content type called "category".
In "product" node i have an entity reference field to "category" nodes (only one category per product).

I have a views page which is displaying products, and a filter by category (category field from product content type), but i can't filter products with the same category value.

I tried [Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter) module, but i got an unexpected error.

Question: How can i filter my views with category? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

- Create a view listing Content of type Product.
- Click on add in RELATIONSHIPS section.
- Search for Referenced Entity via your field in Product (for example field_category).
- Require this relationship.
- In FILTER CRITERIA add any field you want in the referenced
  entity(Category).

N.B: if you want to expose this filter to users check Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it.